# Laravel 5.3 : issues in json structure after removing an item from an array

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

I have an array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => first 
            [description] => first item
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => second 
            [description] => second item
        )

)
```

And remove an item from the array using collection `forget()` method

```
$new = collect($arr);
$new->forget(0);
echo json_encode($new->all());
```

Here is the json output of the above

```
{"1":{"title":"second ","description":"second item"}}
```

But i am expecting a json like this

```
[{"title":"second ","description":"second item"}]
```

Also how can i re index the above array after applying `forget()` method??

Answer (score 1):

Start Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => first 
            [description] => first item
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => second 
            [description] => second item
        )

)
```

You remove the first element of the array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => second 
            [description] => second item
        )

)
```

`json_encode` on this array, returns this:
`{"1":{"title":"second ","description":"second item"}}`

So the output that you have, is correct.

You need to run `json_encode` on this array, for the output that you want:

```
Array
(
    [title] => second 
    [description] => second item
)
```

You can use, for example, the [array_shift](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) function for this:

```
$new = collect($arr);
$new->forget(0);
echo json_encode(array_shift($new->all()));
```

Another example is the [array_values](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function, in case you want more than one array:

```
$new = collect($arr);
$new->forget(0);
echo json_encode(array_values($new->all()));
```